# What is the best workflow solution for editing a movie in FCPX and creating specific effects for it in Motion 5?

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, motion

Since there is no way to send a clip directly to Motion 5 from Final Cut Pro X, only to open up general effects, transitions and generators; what is the best workflow for actually using Final Cut Pro X for a specific clip?

Let's say I have a movie that is five minutes long, and that I want to, every minute, create a floating text with some kind of motion following behavior. How am I supposed to accomplish this? Export separate clips, import them to Motion 5, do the edits, export the clip again, importing it to Fincal Cut Pro X and replace the old clip? This seems quite cumbersome.

Comment: has your workflow changed since Final Cut Pro X 10.1 was released?

Comment: @LuceGoose Should it have? I haven't seen any updates that would adress this problem. Or?

Comment: Looks like you're right. I found where Apple's white paper on media management in FCPX explicitly addresses this in a footnote on page 9: "* Motion projects (such as effects, transitions, and generators) and third-party effects are not managed within the library and must be separately tracked and archived." http://images.apple.com/final-cut-pro/docs/Media_Management.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no really good workflow, I think, yet. The best way I found is to export the video out of FCPX and import it into Motion. Apple thinks that you don't need to work in Motion solely, you only go there to create an effect, title, whatever and then put that thing right on top of a clip *in Final Cut*.

The problem there is that sometimes you'd rather want to have all the editing options Motion offers and just want to see how the video's going to look like. That problem is, to my knowledge, not solved yet. I hope this is all going to change in the future.

Comment: This is such a bummer but I too hope that they'll fix it!

Answer (score 1):

The new way: Create your Effect in Motion, but use it in Final Cut Pro X.

How to:
Start up Motion. Select the category "*Empty*" and choose the "*Final Cut-Title*"-Template. Then create your title and effects in Motion. If you "save" your project you have to select or create a effect-category for FCPX, then it will be published in Final Cut Pro X.

Start Final Cut Pro X. Open your project. Choose your newly created title or effect in the effect-library and apply it to your clips.

P.S.:
If you want to adjust an effect-parameter from within Final Cut Pro X, just rightclick it in Motion and select "publish" in the dropdown-menu. It will be available in the Videoeffect-Pane of FCPX.

Comment: So, how would this for example apply to motion track a title to a moving object or creating muzzle flashes?

Comment: Motion tracking is imho one of very few instances that doesn't work that way. I think in that case you have to use Motion.

Comment: My description was more general.

Comment: I think Apple are pretty clear with how you should handle generic effects, such as titles not interacting with the material it's overlayed upon, and I think this workflow makes a lot of sense. However, when it comes to more specific uses it feels like they leave the users pretty much in the dark. I would love for them to make a tutorial on how to for example create an action movie (complete with muzzle flashes and explosions) in FCPX and Motion 5, but I doubt they could show us something tantalizing, workflow vice.

Comment: I'm sure they will fix it. Maybe with FCPX Version 2 or 3.

Comment: Let's hope so!!

Comment: It's not just motion tracking, in the sense of Motion's motion tracking behaviors. It's also anything where you're matching animation to the video in multiple places, even if you do it with keyframing.

Answer (score 0):

Here a tool to convert Final Cut X timelines into Motion 5 timelines.
http://www.ilgattohanuovecode.it/tool/final-cut-round-trip/

Answer (score 0):

There's a paid tool Xsend Motion - https://fxfactory.com/info/xsendmotion/

You can share your timeline or compound clip through this program directly to Apple Motion.